# FFMPEG | m3u8 playlist and ts chunks with current time

Tags: ffmpeg

I want to create a m3u8 file named out.m3u8. It will create chunks ts files with the name: %H%M%S.ts.

I tried this code and it creates ts files according to the current time, but I do not know how to create the out.m3u8 file.

```
ffmpeg -re -i 'mystream' -vcodec libx264 -vb 500000 -g 60 -vprofile main -acodec aac -ab 128000 -ar 48000 -ac 2 -vbsf h264_mp4toannexb -b 1000k -minrate 1000k -maxrate 1000k -strict experimental -f stream_segment -segment_format mpegts -segment_time 60 -segment_atclocktime 1 -reset_timestamps 1 -strftime 1 /var/www/html/%H%M%S.ts
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `-segment_list out.m3u8`. See [FFmpeg Segment Muxer](https://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg-formats.html#segment) for more info.